# How to Increase/Decrease font size with Pan Gesture?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uipangesturerecognizer

I am applying pan gesture on `UILabel`. I use one finger scale to increase and decrease the size of the `UILabel`.

I tried using `scale` to add and subtract value from font size, but I am not getting the exact result.

```
@objc
func handleRotateGesture(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let touchLocation = recognizer.location(in: self.superview)
    let center = self.center

    switch recognizer.state {
    case .began:

        self.deltaAngle = CGFloat(atan2f(Float(touchLocation.y - center.y), Float(touchLocation.x - center.x))) - CGAffineTransformGetAngle(self.transform)
        self.initialBounds = self.bounds
        self.initialDistance = CGPointGetDistance(point1: center, point2: touchLocation)

    case .changed:
        let angle = atan2f(Float(touchLocation.y - center.y), Float(touchLocation.x - center.x))
        let angleDiff = Float(self.deltaAngle) - angle
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(-angleDiff))
        if let label = self.contentView as? UILabel {


            var scale = CGPointGetDistance(point1: center, point2: touchLocation) / self.initialDistance
            let minimumScale = CGFloat(self.minimumSize) / min(self.initialBounds.size.width, self.initialBounds.size.height)
            scale = max(scale, minimumScale)
            let scaledBounds = CGRectScale(self.initialBounds, wScale: scale, hScale: scale)


            var pinchScale = scale
            pinchScale = round(pinchScale * 1000) / 1000.0


            var fontSize = label.font.pointSize
            if(scale > minimumScale){
                if (self.bounds.height > scaledBounds.height) {
                     //  fontSize = fontSize - pinchScale
                       label.font = UIFont(name: label.font.fontName, size: fontSize - pinchScale)
                   }
                   else{
                      // fontSize = fontSize + pinchScale
                       label.font = UIFont(name: label.font.fontName, size: fontSize + pinchScale)
                   }
            } else {
                label.font = UIFont( name: label.font.fontName, size: fontSize)
            }

             print("PinchScale -- \(pinchScale), FontSize = \(fontSize)")



            self.bounds = scaledBounds

        } else {
            var scale = CGPointGetDistance(point1: center, point2: touchLocation) / self.initialDistance
            let minimumScale = CGFloat(self.minimumSize) / min(self.initialBounds.size.width, self.initialBounds.size.height)
            scale = max(scale, minimumScale)
            let scaledBounds = CGRectScale(self.initialBounds, wScale: scale, hScale: scale)
            self.bounds = scaledBounds
        }

        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

However, we can achieve this using `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`. But how can we do the same effect with `UIPanGestureRecognizer`? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "not getting the exact result" is not a useful problem description. Please state desired outcome vs what actually happens.

Answer (score 2):

Right now you’re adding and removing points to the label’s current font size. I’d suggest a simpler pattern, more consistent with what you’re doing elsewhere, namely just capturing the the initial point size at the start of the gesture and then, as the user’s finger moves, apply a scale to that saved value. So, I’d suggest:

- Define property to save the initial font size:

  ```
  var initialPointSize: CGFloat = 0
  ```
- In the `.began` of the gesture, capture the current size

  ```
  initialPointSize = (contentView as? UILabel)?.font?.pointSize ?? 0
  ```
- In the `.changed`, adjust the font size:

  ```
  let pinchScale = (scale * 1000).rounded() / 1000
  label.font = label.font.withSize(initialPointSize * pinchScale)
  ```

As an aside, I’m not sure that it’s necessary to round the `scale` to three decimal places, but you had that in your original code snippet, so I preserved that.

---

Personally, I’d follow the same basic pattern with the `transform`:

- Define a properties to capture the starting angle and the view’s current `transform`:

  ```
  var initialAngle: CGFloat = 0
  var initialTransform: CGAffineTransform = .identity
  ```
- In the `.began`, capture the current the starting angle and existing transform:

  ```
  initialAngle = atan2(touchLocation.y - center.y, touchLocation.x - center.x)
  initialTransform = transform
  ```
- In the `.changed`, update the `transform`:

  ```
  let angle = atan2(touchLocation.y - center.y, touchLocation.x - center.x)
  transform = initialTransform.rotated(by: angle - initialAngle)
  ```

This saves you from reverse engineering the angle associated with the current transform with `CGAffineTransformGetAngle` and instead just apply `rotated(by:)` to the saved transform.

So this, like the point size and the bounds, represents a consistent pattern: Capture the starting value in `.began` and just apply whatever change you need in `.changed`.

---

A few unrelated observations:

1. All those `self.` references are not needed. It just adds noise that makes it harder to read the code.
2. All of those casts between `CGFloat` and `Float` are not needed. If you use the `atof2` function instead of `atof2f`, they all just work with `CGFloat` without any casting. E.g., instead of

   ```
   let angle = atan2f(Float(touchLocation.y - center.y), Float(touchLocation.x - center.x))
   let angleDiff = Float(self.deltaAngle) - angle
   self.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(-angleDiff))
   ```

   You can just do:

   ```
   let angle = atan2(touchLocation.y - center.y, touchLocation.x - center.x)
   transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle - deltaAngle)
   ```

   You actually don’t need any of those casts that are currently sprinkled throughout the code snippet.
3. All of those `bounds.size.width` and `bounds.size.height` can just be `bounds.width` and `bounds.height` respectively, again removing noise from the code.
4. When adjusting the font size, rather than:

   ```
   label.font = UIFont(name: label.font.fontName, size: fontSize)
   ```

   You should just use:

   ```
   label.font = label.font.withSize(fontSize)
   ```

   That way you preserve all of the essential characteristics of the font (the weight, etc.), and just adjust the size.
5. In your `if let label = contentView as? UILabel` test, the same five lines of code in your `else` clause appear in the `if` clause, too. You should just move those common lines before the `if`-`else` statement, and then you can lose the `else` clause entirely, simplifying your code.